# A* algorithm - Order of expanded nodes

Tags: algorithm, search, graph-theory, dijkstra, a-star

I am wondering why the order of expansion is ACBDG and not just ACG. From what i understand from the A*-algorithm is that is uses the f-value, which is the heuristic value and the real cost combined to determine the next node to expand. Is is that when expanding a node, the previous cost will be the f-value from the next node and current node combined? Or the f-value of the next node and g-value from current node combined?

It seems strange that after expanding the A, C and B nodes that the next node would not be G, as H(G) is lower than H(D). I observe that the real cost is lower to D, but isnt the point of A* to go for the combined heuristic value and the actual cost?

The starting node is A and the goal is G

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this graph from?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the solution be ABCG of length 7, instead of ACG of length 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following steps to the left of the `=>` are the unexpanded nodes, and on the right are the action and the result of the expansion. Nodes on the left contain between the parenthesis the path, the cost of that path, and heuristic value. On the right there is no heuristic value yet. Nodes on the left are sorted by cost of path + heuristic value, with later nodes added after the existing nodes if they have equal sums:

- A(-, 7) => Expand **A from -**: got B(A, 1), C(A, 4)
- C(A, 4, 2), B(A, 1, 6) => Expand **C from A**: got B(AC, 6), D(AC,
  7), G(AC, 8)
- B(A, 1, 6), G(AC, 8, 0), D(AC, 7, 2), B(AC, 6, 6) =>
  Expand **B from A**: got C(AB, 3), D(AB, 5)
- C(AB, 3, 2), D(AB, 5, 2), G(AC, 8, 0), D(AC, 7, 2), B(AC, 6, 6) => Expand **C from AB**: got D(ABC, 6), G(ABC, 7)
- D(AB, 5, 2), G(ABC, 7, 0), G(AC, 8, 0), D(ABC, 6, 2), D(AC, 7, 2), B(AC, 6, 6) => Expand **D from AB**: got C(ABD, 8), G(ABD, 11)
- G(ABC, 7, 0), G(AC, 8, 0), D(ABC, 6, 2), D(AC, 7, 2), C(ABD, 8, 2), G(ABD, 11, 0), B(AC, 6, 6) => Found **G from ABC**, end of search

Comment: I think this is correct. I got the problem from an earlier exam in a course im currently taking. I think there is a misunderstanding in the question, whereas the visited nodes cannot be reconsidered and the path-cost or f-value of a visited node stays unchanged after visited.

Comment: In your reasoning, the C node is visited twice, and the optimal solution is found with ABCG with cost 7 instead of ACG with cost 8. Because of visited nodes being "locked" the shortest path will be found through only expanding new nodes through ACG, if i understood it right.

Comment: I have another question: I believe that the A*algorithm selects the next node by using the heuristic value and actual path cost combined. How does the priority queue select the next node to expand if they got the same f-value. Is it the order of when it arrived in the queue (FIFO)? or is it the node with the lowest heuristic value (nearest goal first) when two nodes has the same f-value.

Comment: @Anders In my answer I assumed it was the order of arrival, to match the expectation in the question. But in the end the programmer gets to decide everything, including that one part.

Comment: Thanks @Dialecticus . I guess it is up to the professors who makes the exam which type of priority queue theyre using. Is revisiting an already visited node using A* a modified version? Or is it up for interpretation what a standard A* algorithm is? For some reason, it seems like for the most part that we have used a queue that "closes" the nodes and only visit the nodes once.

Comment: If you visit nodes only once you'd miss the optimal solution. So again it depends on your decision, which depends on your constraints. If you have enough time to find the perfect solution then visit nodes more than once (but with different paths). Just make sure to avoid loops. If you don't have enough time then visit nodes only once and assume that whatever you find is "good enough".

Comment: @Anders there is another interpretation of "visiting only once". You have to avoid loops, so you visit nodes only once in terms of each node expansion. You don't visit nodes that are in the saved path, but you visit everything you can visit if it's not yet in the saved path.